# How to get link to given row in Google Script / google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to get the hyperlink to the row in Google Script / Google Sheet?

When I tried:

```
 var hyperlink = row[2].hyperlink;
```

the result is:

```
undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the hyperlink of the specific row using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `var hyperlink = row[2].hyperlink;` and `row[2]`. So for example, when `row[2]` is an array and you want to retrieve the hyperlink of the row 3, you can create the link.
- For example, the hyperlink of 1st row is as follows.

  - `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/edit#gid={sheetId}&range=1:1`
  - I think that this can be used.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.
  const rowNumber = 3;  // `row[2]` of `row[2].hyperlink` is the row 3?

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const hyperlink = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/edit#gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}&range=${rowNumber}:${rowNumber}`;
  console.log(hyperlink)
}
```

#### Note:

- Please use this script with enabling V8.